# Как сделать массив строк char?

Tags: c, массивы

Мне нужно сделать массив, содержащий массивы символов (строки).
Я сделал как-то так, но меня терзают смутные сомнения... Подскажите, как сделать правильно? Или мой вариант вполне правильный? Память выделять тоже только через *Heap*, так как программа компилируется без *RTL*. Можно статически объявлять, главное, чтобы элементы можно было заносить в процессе выполнения.

```
char **arr = (char**)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 3); //Здесь сколько байт выделать нужно?
arr[0] = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 5 + 1);
arr[1] = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 5 + 1);
arr[2] = (char*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, 5 + 1);
arr[0] = "Hello";
arr[1] = "Hello";
arr[2] = "Hello";
MessageBoxA(0, arr[1], arr[0], 0);
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, arr[0]);
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, arr[1]);
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, arr[2]);
```

И сколько места выделять нужно двумерному массиву `arr`, если 3 массива в нем будет, три?

Comment: И почему же это первый вызов  `HeapAlloc` выделяет только 3 байта? Откуда взялось это 3?

Comment: @AnT Три элемента — три байта. Одного байта на адрес хватит всем!

Answer (score 3):

"Корневой" массив содержит указатели. Соответственно, байт под него нужно `sizeof(char*) * 3`, если массивов три.

Массивы второго уровня содержат массивы символов с нулём в конце. Соответственно, байт в них должно быть `strlen(s) + 1`.

При написании кода `arr[0] = "Hello"` вы "забываете" прежний указатель, элемент начинает указывать на предвыделенный блок памяти из самой программы. Если вы хотите разместить строку `"Hello"` в выделенном вами блоке, то можете использовать `strcpy`.

Учитывая ваш код и вопросы, по-моему, вы рановато избавляетесь от RTL...

Comment: Спасибо. Я от него не избавлялся, я начал без него) Просто начал проект так писать, решил так и доделать.

Comment: @RemezW Советую начинать с изучения "нормального" режима. Поверьте, в плюсах вам его хватит надолго. Я бы сказал, что на всю жизнь. Усложнять себе жизнь имеет смысл тогда, когда в этом есть польза.

Comment: Не совсем понял про "вы "забываете" прежний указатель". То есть, через = записывать данные в блок нельзя в любом случае? Или можно как-то сделать более правильно, чтобы можно было?

Comment: Посмотрим на код: `int a = 1; a = 2;`. После того, как он будет выполнен, значения 1 больше нигде не будет. На его месте будет значение 2. Вот и в вашем случае адрес был, а потом сплыл, и про него никто не будет знать.

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[10][10];
```

Вот тебе массив: 10 строк по 9 символов